# Save and Load Font/FontColour

Tags: java, swing, fonts, save, load

I have a bunch of customized setting in the program I'm working on where the user can change the font and the font colour and also the background colour but for now ill start with the font and font colour currently I'm saving the title to a text file with this:

```
bSave = new JButton("Save");
    bSave.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    bSave.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
    mnConfiguration.add(bSave);
    bSave.addActionListener(this);
    f.setVisible(true);
    // ----------------Save Config------------------------------
    bSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                saveProperties();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,
                        "Properties were saved successfully!");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,
                        "Error saving properties file: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    try {
        loadProperties();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane
                .showMessageDialog(f,
                        "The config.properties file does not exist, default properties loaded.");
    }
    tName.setText(configProps.getProperty("Name"));
    tFrom.setText(configProps.getProperty("Start"));
    tTo.setText(configProps.getProperty("End"));


    // -----------------------Saving-----------------------
private void saveProperties() throws IOException {

    configProps.setProperty("Name", tName.getText());
    configProps.setProperty("Start", tFrom.getText());
    configProps.setProperty("End", tTo.getText());
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(configFile);
    configProps.store(outputStream, "host setttings");
    outputStream.close();

}

// ------------------------Loading--------------
private void loadProperties() throws IOException {
    Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
    // sets default properties
    defaultProps.setProperty("Name", "Randomiser");
    defaultProps.setProperty("Start", "1");
    defaultProps.setProperty("End", "100");
    rGreen.setSelected(true);
    bgBlack.setSelected(true);
    tbgBlack.setSelected(true);
    bbgBlack.setSelected(true);
    tfcWhite.setSelected(true);
    btWhite.setSelected(true);
    boWhite.setSelected(true);

    configProps = new Properties(defaultProps);

    // loads properties from file
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(configFile);
    configProps.load(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();

}
```

This works great for saving JTextFeilds but when I try to do something like this:

```
configProps.setProperty("tFont", tTitle.getfont());
```

it doesn't like it.
any idea how I can Save the font and font colour?

Comment: Save the properties of the font, they must be converted to String. You could use the Prefer des API which allows you to use all the primitive types

Comment: so i could do something like:
String test = tTitle.getFont();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Properties` manages `String` keys and `String` value pairs.  In order to store a complex object, you would need to convert the properties of the object to `String` values, which you could then convert back when you read them, for example...

```
configProps.setProperty("tFont.size", Integer.toString(tTitle.getFont().getSize()));
configProps.setProperty("tFont.name", tTitle.getFont().getFontName());
configProps.setProperty("tFont.color", Integer.toString(tTitle.getForeground().getRGB()));
```

You could also make use of the [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) which allows you to set primitive values.  With this API, however, you will lose control over where the values are stored, as this becomes system dependent.

```
Preferences pref = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(this.getClass());
pref.putInt("tFont.size", tTitle.getFont().getSize());
pref.put("tFont.name", tTitle.getFont().getFontName());
pref.putInt("tFont.color", tTitle.getForeground().getRGB());
```

**Updated**

When loading values you need to convert the `String` property values back to there required types, for example...

```
String sizeValue = configProps.getProperty("tFont.size", "12");
int size = Integer.parseInt(sizeValue);

String fontName = configProps.getProperty("tFont.name", UIManager.getFont("Label.font").getName());

String colorValue = configProps.getProperty("tFont.color", Integer.toString(Color.BLACK.getRGB()));
Color color = new Color(Integer.parseInt(colorValue), true);
```

You should also be prepared for the keys/values to not exist and either take precautions against it or provide default values

Comment: Thanks for your help I can't seem to get the Preferences to work has an error with setProperty but the top one worked a treat but I can't seem to get this to work still with tTitle.setFont(configProps.getProperty("tFont.name"));

Comment: Sorry, copying and pasting code on the ipad, forget to update the method names

Comment: I think I like the first option better but it still pops an error on setFont when I try to set fontsize with this: tName.setFont().setSize(configProps.getProperty("End"));

Comment: You have to convert the `String` value in the properties to a `int`, you also need to allow for the fact that the property may not exist in the `Properties`

Comment: I've got defaults set up and ready to go but still struggling with converting the string into a int I tried reading up on it but had no luck, I'm still really new to java swing would you be able to give me an example please. Sorry to be a bother

Comment: This is my attempt at it: int fg = tName.getForeground().getRGB();
  String ffg = "" + fg;
  ffg = (configProps.getProperty("nFont.color"));

Answer (score 0):

`Font` is a complex type and .properties contains strings in most cases.
You may save font properties, such as size, style and family:

```
configProps.setProperty("tFont.size", tTitle.getFont().getSize());
configProps.setProperty("tFont.name", tTitle.getFont().getFontName());
configProps.setProperty("tFont.color", tTitle.getForeground());
```

Comment: so it likes: 
    configProps.setProperty("tFont.name", tTitle.getFont().getFontName());

but puts an error to the rest, and I can't get any of the to get the property

Comment: configProps.setProperty("tFont.color", tTitle.getForeground()); 
configProps.setProperty("tFont.size", tTitle.getFont().getSize()); don't work

Comment: Yeah, they are not strings. Also you may want to use `font.getName` instead of `getFontName` and `int font.getStyle()` to save bold style